# Proof that the average of a convex curve is inside the curve.

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, curves

Let $\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t): [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be closed curve in the plane. The region inside the closed curve is $D$, therefore $\boldsymbol{\gamma} = \partial D$ (boundary of $D$).

Let's say that $D$ is convex, that is $\forall \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in D$ implies that $ \mathbf{x}\lambda + (1-\lambda)\mathbf{y} \in D$ for $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

The average of the boundary of $D$ is: $$\boldsymbol{\mu} = \frac{1}{b-a} \oint_{\partial D} \boldsymbol{\gamma}(t) dt $$

I want to show that $\boldsymbol{\mu} \in D$.

Can anyone help me with this proof, maybe give me a hint on how to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to assume that $D$ is [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set).

Since $\gamma$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is compact, one has the [following equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum):
$$\mu=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b\gamma(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\gamma\underbrace{\left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)}_{\in D}}_{\textrm{barycenter}\in D},$$
so that $\mu$ is a limit of barycenters of points in $D$, whence a limit of points in $D$ (since $D$ is convex) and finally the average $\mu\in D$ (since $D$ is closed).

**Reminders.**

1. A barycenter of points in a convex set is itself in the convex set.
2. A limit of points in a closed set is itself in the closed set.

Comment: How does your answer show that $\mu \in D$? Can you explain it further? How can I show that the right-hand side is in $D$?

Comment: I have expanded a bit my answer, is that clearer now?

Comment: Yes, now is clearer. I didn't understand your question before, because I didn't know that the barycentric of points in a convex set stays in the convex set. I guess I need a new question for that :D

Comment: It is really straightforward, the barycenter of two points $a,b\in D$ is of the form $\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b$, with $\lambda\in[0,1]$ and whence lies in $D$ by the very definition of $D$ being convex. Now, if the barycenter is between more than two points, you proceed by induction splitting the sum of the barycenter in two pieces (the first term and the others) and you conclude using the same reasoning than before.